# JQuery not adding element not giving an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a content `<div>` to an element and also a `<h1>` element to another. The content dive gets added into the html, but not the h1 and I'm not getting any error either.

This is the relevant code:

```
var content = $("<div>").attr({"class": "section-content", "id": "content", 
   "style": "max-height: 500px;overflow-y: scroll; padding-top:0;padding-
   bottom:0;"}).appendTo(".Extrablox");
console.log("Adding content");
var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo(".content");
console.log("Added content");
```

What do I need to change to get the h1 added?

Comment: you are trying to add the `h1` heading to an element with class `.content`.... try changing it to `#content` or simply replace the string with `content` variable to add it to the content container box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo(".content");
```

tries to add h1 to a div with a class of name content. however the div you add has a class named section-content and an id named content.

change

```
var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo(".content");
```

to

```
var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo(".section-content");
```

or

```
var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo("#content");
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify to `var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo("#content");`

```js
var content = $("<div>").attr({
    "class": "section-content",
    "id": "content",
    "style": "max-height: 500px;overflow-y: scroll; padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;"
  })
  .appendTo(".Extrablox");
console.log("Adding content");
var textcont = $("<h1>").appendTo("#content");
console.log("Added content");
```

```css
.Extrablox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="Extrablox"></div>
```